# Rails 4 Active Record Joins and Includes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, ruby-on-rails-4, model-associations

I have two models: Place and Subfilter

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subfilter
end

class Subfilter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :places
end
```

The following two queries return the same value as `Place.all`

1. `Place.joins(:subfilter)`
2. `Place.includes(:subfilter)`

Help! Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I don't know what you expect it to be ... `Place.includes(:subfilter).where(subfilter: { name: 'Subfilter #1' })` will get the Place that have a subfilter associated with which is named `Subfilter #1'.

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to yield the same, however these 2 statements don't do exactly the same thing.

```
Place.joins(:subfilter)
```

Produces the following SQL

```
SELECT places.* FROM places INNER JOIN subfilters ON subfilters.place_id = places.id

Place.includes(:subfilter)
```

Produces 2 SQL statements

```
SELECT places.* FROM places
```

AND

```
SELECT subfilters.* FROM subfilters
```

The includes helps with eager loading, that is if you want to loop over places e.g.

```
@places.each do |place|
   puts place.subfilter.name
end
```

You can read more about this here under joining tables and eager loading. 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: Hi Iceman, thanks for this input. Do you know what I need to do if I want a table where each row contains all the variables for a Place and  its Subfilter?  e.g. name | lat | lng | title (where title is the subfilters title). Thanks!

Comment: You can always resort to `Place.find_by_sql("select *.all you need from places inner join subfilters on places.id = subfilters.place_id")`

I really recommend that you read this guide, it's loaded with good information
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql

Comment: Place.joins(:subfilter) generates an INNER JOIN not a LEFT OUTER JOIN http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins

Comment: @Octopus-Paul Good catch, copied from the wrong place, corrected.